# Vertical bar usage in SQL

Tags: sql, syntax

I keep running across (someone else's) code like this

```
Case
When (variable & (2|4|8|16)>0) Then ...
WHEN (variable & (1|32)>0 Then ...
...
End
```

I figure what's happening here is it's testing whether there is a 1 or a 0 in the 2^1, 2^2, 2^3, or 2^4 places of the `variable` variable. Is this right? Either way I'm still unclear on why this expression is written in the way it is. I'm unable to find any documentation on this logic mostly because I don't know what to really call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the "pipe" symbol `|` corresponds to the bitwise OR operator, whereas the ampersand `&` corresponds to the bitwise AND operator (at least in some databases).

They're checking bits using those bitwise operators. The most likely reason they are doing this the way they did, is for "improved readability". E.g. it is easier to see which bits are being checked when writing

```
2|4|8|16 -- rather than 30
1|32     -- rather than 33
```

Comment: Well, from the question, we will never know... Maybe they were afraid to use SQL `boolean` types. Maybe their database didn't have any `boolean` types

Comment: Makes perfect sense. And my guess as to why they're doing it like this is that it might represent a lot of boolean columns. This way they can store a lot of info in one field. And since this table is generally not supposed to be read by humans it' fine.

Comment: @Brad: I suppose that's the reasoning. I'm not sure though, if sophisticated databases cannot optimise dozens of `boolean` columns themselves (storing them together as integers internally). And I guess for indexing performance, true `booleans` would be better, too, unless `variable` explicitly had a bitmap index

Comment: @LukasEder yeah, could be easier for the machine doing the logging though. I just don't know (and don't have the ability to ask unfortunately).

Comment: @Brad: Well, some things just are the way they are... :)